# How to default to GitHub hosted runners if all self-hosted runners are unavailable?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-runners

I have created a self-hosted runner. On my workflow, when describing the job, I use `runs-on: self-hosted`. But if my self-hosted runner is offline, there won't be any other runner to run that job.

Is there a way to use self-hosted runners when its online, but to let the job run on GitHub hosted runners, if no self-hosted is available?

Comment: Diogo please post your finding regarding group as an answer.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej thanks for helping finding a path.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the desired behavior can be accomplished using runner groups. A GitHub runners group can have both GitHub hosted and self-hosted runners and a [GitHub workflow job can be specified to run on a group](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/using-self-hosted-runners-in-a-workflow#using-groups-to-route-jobs):

```
    runs-on:
      group: hybrid-runners
```

If the `hybrid-runners` group have a self-hosted runner and a GitHub hosted runner, in each run, one of the runners will be used for that job. If the self-hosted runner is offline, then the job will necessarily default to the GitHub hosted runner.

AFAIK, there is no way to control a preferred runner and its unknown if GitHub already have a bias towards using GitHub hosted or self-hosted runners.

Comment: In the current version of the documentation, it states: "[Runner groups can only have larger runners or self-hosted runners as members.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#choosing-runners-in-a-group)". So it doesn't seem to be possible anymore?